# Commerce custom taxtype wrong calculation

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to add spanish [recharge](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impuesto_sobre_el_Valor_A%C3%B1adido_(Espa%C3%B1a)#:%7E:text=Los%20comerciantes%20minoristas%20que%20sean,IAE%20as%C3%AD%20se%20lo%20permita.) tax to [drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce). It is calculated like VAT but only for some customer in a B2B bussines, and It is a second tax, that is, you have to calculate VAT and "recharge" in the same order. Because It works more or less like European Union Vat tax type, I have copied this file and I have changed it like this:

```
/**
 * Provides spanish recharge tax.
 *
 * @CommerceTaxType(
 *   id = "spanish_recharge",
 *   label = "Recargo equivalencia",
 * )
 */
class RecargoTaxType extends LocalTaxTypeBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
    $form['rates'] = $this->buildRateSummary();
    $form['rates']['#markup'] = $this->t('Recharge:');
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function resolveZones(OrderItemInterface $order_item, ProfileInterface $customer_profile) {
       
    $zones = $this->getZones();
    /** @var \Drupal\address\AddressInterface $customer_address */
    $customer_address = $customer_profile->get('address')->first();
    $customer_country = $customer_address->getCountryCode();
    $customer_zones = $this->getMatchingZones($customer_address);
    if (empty($customer_zones)) {
      // The customer is not in the EU.
      return [];
    }
       
    $order = $order_item->getOrder();
    $store = $order->getStore();
    $store_address = $store->getAddress();
    $store_country = $store_address->getCountryCode();
    $store_zones = $this->getMatchingZones($store_address);
    $store_registration_zones = array_filter($zones, function ($zone) use ($store) {
      /** @var \Drupal\commerce_tax\TaxZone $zone */
      return $this->checkRegistrations($store, $zone);
    });
   
    $customer_tax_number = '';
    if (!$customer_profile->get('tax_number')->isEmpty()) {
      /** @var \Drupal\commerce_tax\Plugin\Field\FieldType\TaxNumberItemInterface $tax_number_item */
      $tax_number_item = $customer_profile->get('tax_number')->first();
      if ($tax_number_item->checkValue('european_union_vat')) {
        $customer_tax_number = $tax_number_item->value;
      }
    }
    
    // Since january 1st 2015 all digital goods sold to EU customers
    // must use the customer zone. For example, an ebook sold
    // to Germany needs to have German VAT applied.
    $taxable_type = $this->getTaxableType($order_item);
    $year = $order->getCalculationDate()->format('Y');
    $is_digital = $taxable_type == TaxableType::DIGITAL_GOODS && $year >= 2015;
    if (empty($store_zones) && !empty($store_registration_zones)) {
      // The store is not in the EU but is registered to collect VAT for
      // digital goods.
      $resolved_zones = [];
      if ($is_digital) {
        $resolved_zones = $customer_tax_number ? [$zones['ic']] : $customer_zones;
      }
    }
    elseif ($customer_tax_number && $customer_country != $store_country) {
      // Intra-community supply (B2B).
      $resolved_zones = [$zones['ic']];
    }
    elseif ($is_digital) {
      $resolved_zones = $customer_zones;
    }
    else {
      // Physical products use the origin zone, unless the store is
      // registered to pay taxes in the destination zone. This is required
      // when the total yearly transactions breach the defined threshold.
      // See http://www.vatlive.com/eu-vat-rules/vat-registration-threshold/
      $resolved_zones = $store_zones;
      $customer_zone = reset($customer_zones);
      if ($this->checkRegistrations($store, $customer_zone)) {
        $resolved_zones = $customer_zones;
      }
    }

    return $resolved_zones;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildZones() {
    // Avoid instantiating the same labels dozens of times.
    $labels = [
      'standard' => $this->t('Standard'),
      'intermediate' => $this->t('Intermediate'),
      'reduced' => $this->t('Reduced'),
      'second_reduced' => $this->t('Second Reduced'),
      'super_reduced' => $this->t('Super Reduced'),
      'special' => $this->t('Special'),
      'zero' => $this->t('Zero'),
      'vat' => $this->t('Recharge'),
    ];

    $zones = [];
    $zones['es'] = new TaxZone([
      'id' => 'es',
      'label' => $this->t('Spain'),
      'display_label' => $labels['vat'],
      'territories' => [
        // Spain without Canary Islands, Ceuta and Melilla.
        ['country_code' => 'ES', 'excluded_postal_codes' => '/(35|38|51|52)[0-9]{3}/'],
      ],
      'rates' => [
        [
          'id' => 'standard',
          'label' => $labels['standard'],
          'percentages' => [
            ['number' => '0.052', 'start_date' => '2012-09-01'],
          ],
          'default' => TRUE,
        ],
        [
          'id' => 'reduced',
          'label' => $labels['reduced'],
          'percentages' => [
            ['number' => '0.014', 'start_date' => '2012-09-01'],
          ],
        ],
        [
          'id' => 'super_reduced',
          'label' => $labels['super_reduced'],
          'percentages' => [
            ['number' => '0.005', 'start_date' => '1995-01-01'],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ]);
    
    return $zones;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies(OrderInterface $order) {
    $store = $order->getStore();
    
    if ($this->matchesAddress($store) || $this->matchesRegistrations($store)) {
    
      // Check if customer is in "recharge" situation
      $usuario = $order->getCustomerId();
      $user = User::load($usuario);
      if ($user->get('field_isRecharged')->value == 1) {      
        return TRUE;
      }
      else return FALSE;      
    }
    else return FALSE;
  }
  
}
```

I have deleted all countries zones and I have left only Spain. I have defined `applies` function to check if the customer is in this situation and "recharge" needs to be added.
After rebuild cache, I have created a new tax type with this new extension. Then I have two taxes. One with Europen Union Vat extension and the other with my new extension.
In my product variation I have a tax field that point out the type of tax for this product. I use [Commerce Product Tax](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_tax) module to select the right tax percentage for every product. It works good.
My problem is this new tax is not applied in the right way and always return 'standard' percentage even if the product has reduced or super reduced tax, because tax resolver is called only one time. I have added some log messages and this is the sequence:

1. VAT is the first tax calculated. `resolveZones` function in EurepeanUnionVat.php is fired and return spanish zone (standard, reduced and super reduced).
2. `resolve` function in TaxRateResolver.php (Commerce product tax) is fired and select the right percentage reading product variation tax field. It returns "reduced" percentage tax.
3. VAT is calculated with reduced tax. That is right.
4. Recharge begin to be calculated. `resolveZones` function, in my custom tax type RecargoTaxType.php, is fired and return spanish zone (standard, reduced and super reduced with its percentages). I have logged it.
5. Nothing more on the log ...
6. The cart is showed with VAT (reduced) and my custom "recharge" but with "standard" percentage.

What I was expecting is on step 5, `resolve` funtion in TaxRateResolver.php were called again to select the right percentage for "recharge", but It isn't called. I don't know why. Then, it adds standard percentage for recharge but It should be "reduced".
Could someone help me with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more test I realised that product variation tax field is applied only for one tax, and then `resolve` function is fired, but It doesn't find a field for my new type of tax.
I have create another field in product variation for my new taxtype and now it works good.